# random process as a function of two random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Let $U$ and $Z$ be independent random variables where $U \sim U(0,1)$ and $Z \sim N(0,1)$, and define the random process $$X_t = Zt^U$$
I'm trying to (a) find the distribution of $X_t$ for fixed $0 \le t \le 1$, and (b) compute the mean, $\mathbb{E}(X_t)$.

So for fixed $t$, it looks like $X_t$ is just some scaled version of the standard normal distribution (since $0 \le t \le 1$ and $0 \le U \le 1 \implies 0 \le t^U \le 1$), which suggests to me that $\mathbb{E}X_t = 0$, but I don't really know how to show that or if it is even true.

Any hints and guidance will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: $\mathbb{E}X_t = \mathbb E Z \, \mathbb E t^U =0$ given independence and $\mathbb E Z =0$.  But $X_t$ is not quite normally distributed for $0 < t < 1$

Comment: I would start by finding the distribution of $t^U$ and then using the standard method for finding the density of the product of two continuous random variables. This may not result in a nice closed form, however.